# What do you call it when you "extend" a word?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, linguistics

On a programming site, I noticed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460404/unexplained-increasement-of-variable

a beautiful word use, "increasement."

Is there a term for, or how would you refer to, that - where you take a word, and use a different "form" of it.

So, you're making up a new "form" of a word which has never been seen before, but it makes sense based on variant "forms" of other words.

(This is sometimes done for humorous effect; and small children sometimes do it: in the example at hand it's just plain pretty.)

By the way notice I use "form" above ... perhaps it is not the best term (maybe there's another term, something like "tense" or ?)

---

Further - relatedly, it occurs to me that children learning language, particularly do this (often humorously to us adults).  Surely, there's a term for this when children do it, since there's plenty of academic interest in such things.

Comment: [Encyclopædia Britannica:](http://www.britannica.com/topic/inflection) ***Inflection,** formerly **flection** or **accidence,** in linguistics, the change in the form of a word (in English, usually **the addition of endings**) to mark such distinctions as tense, person, number, gender, mood, voice, and case.* Are you asking for a term for "non-standard inflection"? Why do you say non-standard ***increasement*** is a "beautiful word use"?

Comment: *performant* is a similarly new use of the word *performance*

Comment: @Josh61 - thanks for that.  It looks like the agglutinator who agglutinated unknowingly was also unaware of the archaicismality.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - ahh, "inflection", thanks for that.  However, how does that interact with "agglutination", do you know?  Are they basically similes ... or not really?

Comment: Surely "inflection" should be put in as an answer, it's precisely what the OP is asking right?

Comment: @Joe Blow: Not sure what you're getting at - are you asking *How do we describe the relationship between the known word **agglutination** and the hypothetical nonce-word **agglutinment**?* Off-hand I can't think of a single root that can *validly* be inflected with both ***-ment*** and ***-ation***. But most likely if there are any such words, custom and practice would either lead to them having different meanings, or one version would end up being classed as "archaic" or some such.

Comment: Hi @Fumble.  Sorry i was unclear.  Below, the suggestion is made ***agglutination*** which seems like a very good answer.  You are suggesting ***inflection*** which also seems to be a very good answer.  how do the terms "agglutinate" and "inflection" compare - - indeed are they just similes, or ?? What do you think?

Comment: @Joe: My bad - I hadn't noticed that answer. I think [some people consider **agglutination** to be **a sub-set of inflection**, contrasted with fusional inflection](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/1g30ct/whats_the_difference_between_the_terms/), and I can easily get my head around the idea that ***agglutinated*** words all have bits tacked onto them, whereas some ***inflected*** ones have their form altered by other means. I also think ***agglutinative*** is more often an attribute of certain languages, but you ***inflect*** words (languages aren't usually called "inflective").

Comment: "idea that agglutinated words all have bits tacked onto them, whereas some inflected ones have their form altered by other means"  Yes, that's a great point.

Comment: The one I hate is *definitize* - what’s wrong with *define*?

Comment: heh.  Funny, I just used "Favoritize" ("processing which happens after user chooses an item to be in favorite category"!)

Comment: @FumbleFingers +1 for *inflection*. There's enough in your 2 substantive comments to simply cut-and-paste the relevant parts to form an answer I'd upvote.

Comment: yes @FumbleFingers it should certainly be an answer - it's probably the correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps you mean the process of attaching suffixes and/or prefixes to a root word to make a whole family of related words, like *hand*, *handy*, *handiness*, *unhand*, *unhanded*, and so on. The name for that is ***[agglutination](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agglutination)*** and languages that rely on this kind of word growth for their grammar are called *agglutinative*. The word itself is an example of Latin agglutination.

> - the formation of derivational or inflectional words by putting together constituents of which each expresses a single definite meaning.

(M-W)

Comment: magnificent, agglutination.  The example at hand is a beautifully agglutinationiseder term.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you make up a new word, generally, it's called a "neologism".  Does that fit here?

[Neologism](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/neologism): (noun)

> 1. a new word, meaning, usage, or phrase.
> 2. the introduction or use of new words or new senses of existing words.
> 3. a new doctrine, especially a new interpretation of sacred writings.
> 4. Psychiatry. a new word, often consisting of a combination of other words, that is understood only by the speaker: occurring most often in the speech of schizophrenics.

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: It's an outstanding point but I'd perhaps think that neologism is the genus and agglutination the species here.  The neologism at hand is an agglutination! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Increasement is already a word.

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/increasement
- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/increasement
- http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Increasement

But I would offer this [Calvin and Hobbes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvin_and_Hobbes) strip:

[image]

Although in this case I suppose you're nouning a noun.

**Edit:** More seriously, you might consider using the verb [suffixing](https://www.google.com/webhp?&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20suffixing):

> append, especially as a suffix.

Comment: hi Kev!  Increasement is an example.  Do you have any idea of an answer to the question?  As I mention, it's a pretty common phenomenon (small children often do it).  The writer in the example at hand did it accidentally (having no clue "increasement" is an archaic word.)  Anyway as I say it's an example, the best answers so far are "agglutination" and "inflection".

Comment: @JoeBlow My answer is **nouning**, but that's a joke based on the Calvin and Hobbes strip. You might also consider **prefixing** or **suffixing**. I've edited my answer to include that as an option.

Comment: "nouning" is a good idea.  It's true that verbing and nouning are ubiquitous in English, quite.  you can use almost any word as a verb in English - it's great.

Answer (score 1):

Cobbled together from earlier comments...

> ***Inflection***, formerly **flection** or **accidence**, in linguistics, the change in the form of a word (in English, usually the addition of endings) to mark such distinctions as tense, person, number, gender, mood, voice, and case.
>   [<sup>(Encyclopædia Britannica)</sup>](http://www.britannica.com/topic/inflection)
>
> ***Agglutination*** is a process in linguistic morphology derivation in which complex words are formed by stringing together morphemes without changing them in spelling or phonetics.  [<sup>(Wikipedia)</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agglutination)
>
> *Some people consider agglutination to be a sub-set of inflection, contrasted with fusional inflection.*
>   [<sup>(reddit/linguistics)</sup>](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/1g30ct/whats_the_difference_between_the_terms/)

---

The general idea being that agglutinated words always have (meaningful) bits tacked onto them, whereas *some* inflected ones have their form altered by other means. Thus I think ***quicksilver***, for example, is an example of agglutination, whereas ***quickly*** is a simple adverb-forming inflection.

I also think agglutinative is more often an attribute of certain *languages* (of which English is not considered to be one), but you inflect *words* (languages aren't usually called "inflective").

Comment: interesting: we have the question "in a given language, what paradigm of inflection is most common?"  So, you feel that in English, inflection is usually *not* commonly done by agglutination, compared to other languages?   So, in contrast, you're thinking perhaps German, say, is agglutination-wise [joke] in terms of inflection?

Comment: @Joe: I note *Don't confuse agglutination with noun compounds. For German to have agglutination in its nouns would mean, for example, that it had completely separate plural and case morphemes either or both of which may be present or absent but in a fixed order* in a [comment to a related Linguistics.SE question.](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/is-there-any-agglutinative-indo-european-language#comment10005_3652) That rather suggests German isn't really considered a good example of an agglutinative language (it's barely mentioned in my Wikipedia article link).

Comment: scheisse - that makes total sense; of course you're right.  In any event, you make a fantastic point that actually English does not really prefer agglutination for its accidence.  Awesome.

Comment: @Joe: I should have answered rather than commenting before (it's probably too late for my answer to overtake EditingFrank's ***agglutinative*** now). All I can say is I didn't know as much about this issue then as I do now (having looked into things a bit), and I assumed we'd prolly get a real linguist's take anyway. And I suspect now that adding ***-ment*** to ***increase*** wouldn't count as agglutination, since you can't really say it's a "morpheme" with an intrinsic "meaning" - it's just a suffix that changes the syntactic role of a word (i.e. - forces/allows it to be a *noun*).

Comment: based on your comment "And I suspect..." it could be I misunderstand what agglutinative means, or I have too simplistic an understanding.  I will delve further, thx

Comment: @Joe: Bear in mind I only said *I suspect...,* so please let me know if my suspicions are incorrect. And if *you* can't figure it out with a bit more delving, I'm sure the guys over a linguistics.SE can authoritatively enlighten both of us.

Answer (score 0):

Nice answers here already, but the problem with agglutination is that it's a very unusual word that most people will be unfamiliar with. Indeed it sounds rather like the process of adding gluten to something...

I would myself go for more of a comedic term which is itself agglutinated: I would call it ***Extenderization***. Everyone can relate to that term and smile at its usage ;)